# routeparams not working in ng-repeat NO RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive, ngroute

Im working on a shoppingCart project and want to bring data into views dynamically so Im calling routeParams in template.html but it is arriving normally as checked via  but it isnt working with ng-repeat.

index.html

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-href="#/store/{{something.name}}/{{ child.name }}">{{ child.display_name }}</a>
```

routing in app.js

```
    when('/store/:Department/:Category', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/template.html',
        controller: storeController
    }).
```

controller.js

```
function storeController($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, DataService) {

    $scope.name = "storeController";
    $scope.$route = $route;
    $scope.$location = $location;
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
    $scope.Category = $routeParams.Category;
}
```

store.js

```
function store() {
    this.fruits = [
        new product("APL", "Apple", "Eat one every day to keep the doctor away!", 12, 90, 0, 2, 0),
        new product("BAN", "Banana", "These are rich in Potassium and easy to peel.", 4, 120, 0, 2, 1)];
}
```

template.html

`<pre>$routeParams.Category = {{$routeParams.Category}}</pre>`

I really need this to work otherwise I would have to call it like store.fruits,store.vegetables and would have to make separate files too for each of them. Please HELP

Comment: where is ng-repeat code ?

Comment: <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 animate" ng-repeat="product in store.{{$routeParams.Category}} | orderBy:'name' | filter:search">

Comment: please jus take a look, i really need this to work to Understand why ng-repeat isnt accepting routeParams, might that be a bug or if there's any other way around?

Comment: ng-repeat="product in store[$routeParams.Category].....

Comment: nope ...dint work..please help..for a second I was so excited that this is what I was missing but then again ;(

Comment: Holy **** it worked!!!

Comment: I have no words, Thank You thank you..for a moment you were a god to me..

Comment: Glad that it work. I posted it as answer. please accept it so that it become resolve question. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is this line

```
<li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 animate" ng-repeat="product in store.{{$routeParams.Category}} | orderBy:'name' | filter:search">
```

Change it to this

```
<li class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 animate" ng-repeat="product in store[$routeParams.Category] | orderBy:'name' | filter:search">
```